# Using 'dummy' pointers just for comparison

Tags: c, pointers

I have a struct that contains a string (character pointer).

This string/array should be in the form of one of the following:

1. contain actual string data
2. no actual data, just should be able to show it's in something called `STATE_1`
3. same as above, but `STATE_2`

I want to be able to check if a 'string' is in `STATE_1` or `STATE_2`, and do something differently than if it contained actual data. If I had only one state, I could use a null pointer.

I tried something along the lines of this, but it leads to undefined behavior.

```
char *STATE_1, *STATE_2;
...
if(tstruct.string == STATE_1 || tstruct.string == STATE_2){
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's undefined because you're taking the *value* of these pointers which are not initialized.  "Dummy pointers" have to point to something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reserve two static addresses. They're guaranteed to be unique.

```
static char STATE_1[1];
static char STATE_2[1];

if (tstruct.string == STATE_1 || tstruct.string == STATE_2) {
    ...
}
```

These could be global variables or they could be static locals, either one.

Comment: Good on you for being able to understand the question. If OP plans on having many instances of this structure, then he or she will not be able to change the contents of this string differently over different instances. I, for one, haven't been able to figure out where the question says that no such plans are in mind. If this is really OP's intention, then I don't really see any need to even declare that string within this structure to begin with. But as I initially stated - if you've understood this question correctly, then I guess that this solutions answers it.

Comment: Nice way to get rid of &-notation!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I guess you want something like this:

```
char STATE_1, STATE_2; // dummy 'char's for 2. and 3.

if (tstruct.string == &STATE_1 || tstruct.string == &STATE_2) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1) You can have a variable in the struct that is of type 
enum stringState which can be 0,1 or 2 (0 means String has data, 1 means State-1 and 2 means State-2). The disadvantage is you have to modify stringState everytime you change the data, and if you forget to do it, there will be consequences.

2) The string itself can have the value "STATE1" or "STATE2" and you can then do strcmp with "STATE1" or "STATE2" otherwise it will have actual data (STATE0).